# creationTimestamp: null for Kubernetes replication controller template

Tags: docker, scheduling, kubernetes

What does it mean when the `creationTimestamp` for the template is `null`?

```
"template": {
          "metadata": {
            "creationTimestamp": null,
            "labels": {
              "name": "kube-template"
            }
          },
```

Comment: Is this snippet from running `kubectl get rc`? Is there a populated creationTimestamp in the ReplicationController metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template in the ReplicationControllerSpec defines the template for a Pod that the ReplicationController *will* create, but since it's an abstract *template*, it doesn't make sense for it to have a creation time. Once the ReplicationController creates a pod, the CreationTimestamp will be set to the time the Pod was created at.

The ReplicationController also has its own metadata (not in the template) which should include the CreationTime of the ReplicationController object.